# Vapor: sending post requests

Tags: swift, server, recaptcha, vapor

I am trying to send an HTTP request using Vapor, to verify a recaptcha

[Google's Captcha api](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) is defined as follows:

URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify METHOD: POST

| POST Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| secret | Required. The shared key between your site and reCAPTCHA. |
| response | Required. The user response token provided by the reCAPTCHA client-side integration on your site. |
| remoteip | Optional. The user's IP address. |

So I need to make a POST request with 2 parameters (secret and response).

In Swift i have:

```swift
func routes(_ app: Application throws {
    app.on(.POST, "website_form") { req -> EventLoopFuture<View> in
        var form: FromRequest = /*initial values*/
        /*decode form data*/
        
        do {
            req.client.post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify") { auth_req in
                try auth_req.content.encode(CaptchaRequestBody(secret: "6Lfoo98dAAAAALRlUoTH9LhZukUHRPzO__2L0k3y", response: form.recaptcha_response), as: .formData)
                auth_req.headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
            }.whenSuccess { resp_val in
                print("Response: \(resp_val)")
            }
        }
    } 
    /* More code */
}

struct CaptchaRequestBody: Content {
    let secret: String
    let response: String
}
```

After running the post request, I get following error code:

```json
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "missing-input-secret"
  ]
}
```

I can not find any solution that works, even the official Vapor docs were of no use, could someone please help me?

Comment: What happens if you change the encode type to .urlEncodedForm instead of .formData?

Comment: You probably need to send/receive raw data (octet-stream). Vapor usually only allows you to send receive JSON data (string). It is possible to send receive raw data but not so simple

Comment: @Nick That fixed the issue! I got confused between the two. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google API requires requests to be URL-encoded forms. By using the `.formData` setting, you are enforcing MultiPart.

Change the setting to `.urlEncodedForm`, which ensures the request conforms to the Google API requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick stated: the problem was that instead of `.formData`, I needed to use `.urlEncodedForm`.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the tip!